# Prove that $X$ is regular and second countable iff $X$ is a separable metrizable space

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ is $T_1$ space. Prove that $X$ is regular and second countable iff $X$ is a separable metrizable space.

Proof: $\rightarrow$

since $X$ is second countable that implies that $X$ is separable i think i am done here.

for the converse i am having trouble any help will be appreciate it thanks

Comment: You need to prove that $X$ is metrizable as well. This is not trivial. In fact this is Urysohn's metrization theorem.

Answer (score 0):

The converse direction can be done the following way. Equip $X$ with a metric $d$. Let $(a_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\subseteq X$ be dense. Then $\{ B_{1/k}(a_n) : n\in \mathbb{N}, k\in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 1} \}$ (balls of radius $1/k$ centered at $a_n$) is a countable basis of $X$ and therefore is $X$ separable.

Let $A\subseteq X$ a closed set and $x\in X$ and $x\notin A$, we need to find open neighborhoods $U,V$ of $A$ and $x$ respectively such that $U\cap V= \emptyset$. As $A$ is closed and $x\notin A$ we get $D:=d(x,A):=inf_{a\in A} d(x,a)>0$. Then $U:=\{ y\in X : d(y, A)<D/2 \}$ and $V:=B_{D/2}(x)$ do the job.